# global variable in python that doesn't make change in sub function

Tags: python, dictionary, variables, scope, switch-statement

## So why result doesn't change? result is global but it will return zero even when print(result) in def add() print correct answer.

```
number = int(input("enter your first num: "))
operation = input("enter your operation: ")
second_number = int(input("enter your second num: "))

def cal(num1,op,num2):
    result = 0
    def add():
        result = num1+num2
        print(result)
    def multiply():
        result =  num1 * num2
    def devide():
        if not num2==0:
            result = num1 / num2
        else:
            result = 'num2 can\'t be zero'
    def default():
        print("Incorrect option")
    switch = {
        '+':add,
        '*':multiply,
        '/':devide
    }
    switch.get(op,default)()
    return result

            
    
print(cal(number,operation,second_number))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global result was outside the scope.

```
number = int(input("enter your first num: "))
operation = input("enter your operation: ")
second_number = int(input("enter your second num: "))


def cal(num1, op, num2):

    def add():
        result = num1+num2
        return result

    def multiply():
        result = num1 * num2
        return result

    def devide():
        if not num2 == 0:
            result = num1 / num2
            return result
        else:
            result = 'num2 can\'t be zero'
            return result

    def default():
        print("Incorrect option")
        switch = {
        '+': add,
        '*': multiply,
        '/': divide
        }
    return switch.get(op, default)()


print(cal(number, operation, second_number))


Python program that uses global
def method():
    # Change "value" to mean the global variable.
    # ... The assignment will be local without "global."
    global value
    value = 100

value = 0
method()

# The value has been changed to 100.
print(value)
100`


Python program that uses nonlocal
def method():

    def method2():
        # In nested method, reference nonlocal variable.
        nonlocal value
        value = 100

    # Set local.
    value = 10
    method2()

    # Local variable reflects nonlocal change.
    print(value)

# Call method.
method()
100
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. What do you mean outside the scope. I defined global variable like this and I could change it in other programming languages like jave or c++ but I don't know how the scope of variable works in pythonn. Could you please explain it more or give me link to read more about it.

Comment: You need the **global** definition in each function you use the variable

Comment: The global keyword didn't work but when I add nonlocal keyword it works. Is that possible to give me quick explanation what is the deference of global and nonlocal?

Comment: Please check my code in the answer I have edited it and wrote an example there, I will help you understand the difference

Comment: Thanks a lot that makes more sense to me. I had hard time to understand it. I want to just make sure that I understand correctly so when I want to use nested method I should use nonlocal otherwise I should use global. is that right?

Answer (score 0):

The `result` variables in the operation functions are in a different scope to the `cal` function. Have those functions return a value and then return that from `cal` and you will get the desired behaviour.

```py
def cal(num1,op,num2):
    def add():
        return num1+num2
    def multiply():
        return num1 * num2
    def devide():
        if not num2==0:
            result = num1 / num2
        else:
            result = 'num2 can\'t be zero'
        return result
    def default():
        print("Incorrect option")
    switch = {
        '+':add,
        '*':multiply,
        '/':devide
    }
    return switch.get(op,default)()
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I also have another question. Result is global in cal function so it doesn't mean each function in cal can change result value? Is the scope of variable different in python compare to other programing languages?